# Linux bash script stuck in sleep state

Tags: linux, bash

I use the SpiderOak client to backup my NAS server data to the cloud. For months this has been working well. However, today, after running for a while, the cronjob process got stuck in a sleep state.  I need help figuring out why and how to fix

I recently lost the cronjob script that had been working well, so I had to write up a new bash script. Maybe I made a mistake. Here it is:

```
#!/bin/sh
WORKING_FILE=/volume1/Volume_1/spideroak.lock
RESULT_FILE=/volume1/Volume_1/spideroak.log

# Cancel if there is an ongoing backup
if [ -f "$WORKING_FILE" ]
  then
    echo "Error: $WORKING_FILE already exists; backup is already running."
   exit 1;
  fi

# Run backup and save results to file with the name that gets checked above
/opt/SpiderOakONE/usr/bin/SpiderOakONE --batchmode --verbose --redirect="$WORKING_FILE"

# Rename log once backup is complete
mv "$WORKING_FILE" "$RESULT_FILE"

# Set log file permissions and exit
chmod 644 "$RESULT_FILE"
echo "Backup complete. Result saved to $RESULT_FILE"
```

I also recently updated the firmware of the NAS but don't know whether that could play a role by putting long-lasting processes to sleep. If I replace the backup command with something that only takes a few seconds to  complete, everything works. eg: if I replace `--batchmode --verbose` with `--selection` and leave everything else as is.

The NAS is a Synology DS-216+ running `DSM 6.0.2-8451 Update 4` firmware

Comment: Using the existence of a plain file as a process lock is probably a bad idea.  If at any point your cron job killed or the NAS restarted while it's running, the .lock file won't be removed, putting it into a permanent state of "already running".  Consider using something like [`flock`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/flock) for locking instead.

Comment: Instead of checking for the presence of a file, check for the presence of the process. If need be, store the process ID to a file and check the existence of the process using the saved process ID.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily an answer (although there's a small chance that it can be the answer), I would recommend you to change the location of the "WORKING_FILE" to /tmp -- this folder gets cleared up at every boot (check you Linux distribution make sure this is your default), and it will delete the control file even if your script somehow fails to do that.